# Leveled UITableView without NavigationController

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I have data structured as a tree (and showed in UITableView) and I would like to show it the way it is usually done using `UINavigationController` and pushing child views on to the stack. The problem is that my `UITableView` (in an iPad app) takes only 1/6 of the screen (there is a `UINavigationController` that handles other fullscreen `iPad` screens in this app, so using `NavigationController` to control the levels of table is the good way).

Is there a simple way to get a good visual effect of changing the levels of `TableView` without using `NavigationController`? Right now I just change the data source and reload data, but that does something like a flicker on the screen (the user can't really see, that the structure of the data is tree-like).

I thought of creating a few `TableViews` and then just animating the resize (from full width to 0 the TableView that we are leaving, and from 0 to width at the same time of the another one) of a table just to make something like segue effect - but I am not sure if this is a good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` with `UITableViewRowAnimationLeft` and `UITableViewRowAnimationRight` instead of a default `reloadData`. This will look like the push you are looking for.

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadSections:withRowAnimation:

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code (after you set the proper values:))

```
__block CGRect frame = tableView.frame;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
          frame.origin.x -=tableView.frame.size.width;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        frame.origin.x = yourViewThatContainsTheTable.frame.size.width
        tableView.frame = frame;
        [tableView reloadData];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            frame.origin.x = 0;
            tableView.frame = frame;
        }];
    }];
```

Basically if you are using subclasses of UIView you can use `[UIView animateWith...]` methods to perform simple animations or you can use CAAnimations/CABasicAnimation/CAAnimationGroup/CAKeyframeAnimation for more complex animations on subclasses of UIView.

If you want a custom transition for a UIViewController you can use CATransition.